# Why isn't wordpress recognizing add_rewrite_rule inside my plugin?

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

I'm using a setting from my plugin to generate the rewrite rule:

```
$bioPage = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT settingValue FROM $table_name WHERE settingType='bioPage'");
$post = get_post($bioPage);
$slug = $post->post_name;

add_rewrite_tag('%player%','([^&]+)');

add_rewrite_rule('^'.$slug.'/([^/]*)$','/'.$slug.'/?player=$matches[1]','top');
```

I am getting the correct slug.

I have a url that looks like this:

```
mysite.com/info/?player=joe.smith.01
```

I want it to look like this:

```
mysiste.com/info/joe.smith.01
```

I'm using the `add_rewrite_tag` so WP will grab the variable for the url. When I visit a page url structured like what I'm trying to achieve I get a page not found.

Comment: did you modify htaccess file? try directly there

Comment: I would but I need to use the plugin to alter the rewrite since the htaccess lives outside the theme file.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend modifying the htaccess file if you don't really have to. WP's Rewrite APi should do just fine.

That said, I'm pretty sure you have to go via 'index.php' in the rewrite argument of add_rewrite_rule().

I don't have any way of testing this right now, but something along the lines of the following might work:

```
$bioPage = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT settingValue FROM $table_name WHERE settingType='bioPage'");
$post = get_post($bioPage);
$slug = $post->post_name;
$page_id = $post->ID; //Get the post ID to include in the page_id query var

add_rewrite_tag('%player%','([^&]+)');
add_rewrite_rule('^'.$slug.'/([^/]*)$','index.php?page_id='.$page_id'.&player=$matches[1]','top');
```